# Conceptual question: If directional derivative exists, is it necessarily of this form?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and let $v=(v_1,v_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Question 1)
Suppose the directional derivative $D_vf$ at $c=(p,q)$ exists.

Must $D_vf$ necessarily be of the form:

$$D_vf(c)=v_1f_x(c)+v_2f_y(c)=v\cdot\nabla f(c)?$$

---

I am thinking that the answer should be no?

Because $D_vf$ may exist even if $f_x$ and $f_y$ do not exist, is that true?

---

Question 2)

Suppose we strengthen the conditions, such that $D_vf$ exist at $c$ **for all** $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, is $D_vf$ necessarily of the form $D_vf(c)=v_1f_x(c)+v_2f_y(c)=v\cdot\nabla f(c)?$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0, (x,y) = (0,0) \\ \frac{x^3}{x^2 + y^2}, (x,y) \neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$

$f$ has directional derivatives in all directions at $(0,0)$, and:

$$D_v f((0,0)) = \begin{cases}  \frac{v_1^3}{v_1^2 + v_2^2}, v \neq 0 \\ 0, v = 0 \end{cases}$$

Now:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = 1 \ \& \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = 0$$

The writing you want is not possible for $v = (1,1)$.

Comment: Very nice. Any idea what is the minimal sufficient conditions that $D_vf$ can be written in that form?

Comment: @yoyostein not quite. But I don't think that there are interesting ones that one can impose